# How to read value of check box inside html table which was inserted dynamically into the table cell as inner html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have added multiple check boxes (using "for" loop which is omitted in code section for easy understanding) into each row of a html table dynamically using Java script. The code goes like this,

```
var table = document.getElementById("verifyTable");
var row = table.insertRow(1);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
cell1.innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox' class = 'checkSensors' id='checkSensorsId' value=''>";
```

Then at run time when the check box is checked/unchecked an event is fired using JQuery like this,

```
$(document).on('change', '[type=checkbox]', function() {
    $("table tr td:nth-child(1)").each(function () {
        var checkbox = $(this).html();
        alert(checkbox);
    });
});
```

Unfortunately the inner html text `<input type='checkbox' class = 'checkSensors' id='checkSensorsId' value=''>` is what I receive as output. I can't figure out a way on how to get the value of innerhtml "input" element. Please help me solve this.

Comment: In other words, you want `value` attribute content?

Comment: Why dont you use $("table tr td:nth-child(1) input") for selector and get val()?

Comment: @AdamAzad No, I have to see the state of check box whether if it is checked/unchecked

Comment: do what @Kuzgun said, and use this: .is(":checked") on the item to get the state.

Comment: @AdamAzad Thanks a lot. It worked.

Comment: @Kuzgun Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method.

```js
$(document).on('change', '[type=checkbox]', function() {
     var checkbox = $(this).is(':checked');
        alert(checkbox);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' class = 'checkSensors' id='checkSensorsId' value='vv'/>
```

Comment: Sorry my question was not clear. I have to see the state of check box whether if it is checked/unchecked. Not the value of attribute. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Made a little change on the for selector as per suggestions in comment and got it working.

```
$(document).on('change', '[type=checkbox]', function() {
    $("table tr td:nth-child(1) input").each(function() {
        alert($(this).is(":checked"));
    });
});
```